# Castle Windsor - Dependencies on classes created outside of the castle

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Castle Windsor manages my dependencies on classes `B`, `C`, `D`, ect. They are very complex, so it's a good thing I have Windsor to take care of them for me. `B`, `C`, `D`, ect have a dependency on `A`, which because .net-core lacks the `WebRequestLifestyle`, must be instantiated outside of Castle Windsor.

Is there a way for me to provide an object of class `A` to Castle Windsor at resolve time?

Comment: What is A? and what does it have to do with WebRequestLifestyle?

Comment: @davidfowl `A` is an audit object which monitors everything which occurred during the request, and groups all those actions together

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET Core, the `WebRequestLifestyle` is called `Scoped`. You can retrieve it by 'cross-wiring' the dependency. I'm unsure whether cross-wiring is already built-in to Castle, but otherwise you can achieve this as follows:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // IHttpContextAccessor is required by the GetRequestService method.
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // Usual stuff here
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Cross-wire ASP.NET Core service that needs to be injected
    container.Register(Component.For<A>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(_ => app.GetRequiredRequestService<A>()));

    // Usual stuff here
}
```

In this example, `GetRequestService` is a custom extension method on `IApplicationBuilder` and is defined as follows:

```cs
public static T GetRequiredRequestService<T>(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    where T : class
{
    var accessor = builder.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var context = accessor.HttpContext ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(
        "No HttpContext.");
    return context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<T>();
}
```